# What type of messages can be used in services?(existing and custom)

Tags: ros, services, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I was just curious about what kind of messages I can transmit over services and topics. Is there a list available somewhere which I can refer to  for this? I know that simple messages can be of the following types

1)a built-in type, such as "float32 pan" or "string name"

2)names of Message descriptions defined on their own, such as "geometry_msgs/PoseStamped"

3)fixed- or variable-length arrays (lists) of the above, such as "float32[] ranges" or "Point32[10] points"

4)the special Header type, which maps to std_msgs/Header

Also, what if I want to pass my own class instance as a message? What do I need to do that?

All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38176/what-type-of-messages-can-be-used-in-services?(existing-and-custom)/) by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2012-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello you can look at the type of messages from here

http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg

in order to look what is inside of a specific message header file, you can check its reference

for example here is the laserscan msg

http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html

if you want to create your own services and messages, check out this wiki below

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv

hope these help you

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2